# Java: Why is the background image painted over the buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, paintcomponent

Is it possible to paint update image behind buttons in the same JPanel? I'm trying to get a Menu screen working but when I try to put in a paint loop to update the background image the buttons disappear. Note: These are custom buttons, they are invisible except for a custom image that I put in them using JButton.setIcon if that makes any difference in the rendering.

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage image;
    private int height =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height-37;
    private int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    private JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
    private JButton startButton = new JButton ("Start");

    public MenuPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(width, height);

        try {image = ImageIO.read(new File("stuyrim.png"));}
        catch (Exception e) {Utilities.showErrorMessage(this, e);}

        optionsButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        //      optionsButton.getParent().getParent();
            });
        optionsButton.setOpaque(false);
        optionsButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        optionsButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        optionsButton.setSize(width/10,height/20);
        optionsButton.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        optionsButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        optionsButton.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        optionsButton.setLocation((width/3)-(width/20), (height/7*6)-(height/40));
        Image img = new ImageIcon("GUI Images/Button.png").getImage().getScaledInstance
            (optionsButton.getWidth(),optionsButton.getHeight(),java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        optionsButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        optionsButton.setForeground(Color.white);


        startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        startButton.getParent().getParent().add(new Screen());
        startButton.getParent().getParent().add(new GamePanel());
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        startButton.getParent().getParent().remove(this);
        g.dispose();
            });
        startButton.setOpaque(false);
        startButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        startButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        startButton.setSize(width/10,height/20);
        startButton.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        startButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        startButton.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN, 20));
        startButton.setLocation((width/3*2)-(width/20), (height/7*6)-(height/40));
        Image img1 = new ImageIcon("GUI Images/Button.png").getImage().getScaledInstance
            (optionsButton.getWidth(),optionsButton.getHeight(),java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        startButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
        startButton.setForeground(Color.white);
        add(optionsButton);
        add(startButton);
        setVisible(true);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,width,height, null);
        g.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: What order do you draw them? If you render an image before buttons the buttons will be on top.

Comment: I'm not sure if I actually "draw" the buttons, I just created the buttons in the constructor. Is there a way of rendering the buttons within the paintcomponent method? I've tried revalidate both before and after rendering the image but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: The spacing in my code got all messed up upon pasting, sorry I'm kind of new here, is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: And where is that "loop" that updates background?

Comment: I've taken it out because even this doesn't work. It seems to work as soon as I remove dispose(); though, which is odd.

Comment: I think I just need a way of sequentially rendering the components, background first, then buttons but I'm not sure how you can "render" the buttons

Comment: I can press the area that the buttons take up and it works but the buttons don't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic problems...

The first, as already highlighted by System.exit, you should be calling `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting.

The reason for this is that the `Graphics` context passed to `paintComponent` is a shared resource.  Everything that was painted before your component and everything that is painted after it will share the same `Graphics` context.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting (typically by filling the required space with the background color of the component).

The second is the use of `getGraphics`.  `getGraphics` gets a reference to the last `Graphics` context used to paint the component (and can be `null` if the component hasn't been painted yet), if you use this you painting outside Swings defined paint chain, which can produce random and unpredictable results.

Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, that is, painting occurs at irregular intervals and can occur for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control or don't initiate.

All custom painting should be done within Swing's defined paint chain, by convention, this is typically done by overriding the `paintComponent` method.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: I must admit that I've only called `super` if I wanted to get the background cleared. I've never ever had a problem. And the Javadoc says *"if you do not invoke super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color."*, so it implicitly but clearly allows not calling `super`. I'm confused.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, you could get away with not calling `super.paintComponent`, but it's just safer to do so. The second part is probably where you're seeing an issue.  Because `paintComponent` can be called at anytime, it's overwriting whatever you painted using `getGraphics`, remember, painting is destructive ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Yes. It is possible of course. But one crucial thing is missing in your code. That "loop" you were mentioning. Swing is singlethreaded and it should be updated on `EDT` (Event dispatch thread). In your case, you should use swing `Timer` component to update your GUI and in same time to keep it responsive. Here is a simple demo:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class JPanelDemo {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

    public JPanelDemo() {
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(JPanelDemo::new);
    }

    class Panel extends JPanel {
        Timer timer;

        //Example images
        String[] images = {"C:/Users/yourname/Pictures/Koala.jpg",
                "C:/Users/yourname/Pictures/Flower.jpg"};

        BufferedImage image;
        int counter;

        public Panel() {
            // Use proper component to update your swing gui.
            // This is actually "The paint loop"
            timer = new Timer(0, ae -> {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new File(images[counter]));
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == images.length) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setDelay(5000);
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

I used swing `Timer` to repeatedly update background of `JPanel` for every 5 seconds while in same time my GUI remains responsive.

Beside of that, I found one more problematic thing in your code. You have set `null` layout for your `JPanel`. Avoid that for any cost if you don't want to get into troubles. Use proper layout manager instead.

Comment: Layout managers aren't enough for what I wanted to do but thank you for the explanation on the swing timer. I don't need it for this panel but I'll need it for later when I put in actual graphics on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `super.paintComponent` like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,width,height, null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Can I ask for an explanation of what exactly it does so I know how to use it in the future?

Comment: @user3215804 Sorry for the late response. From this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/80369-what-does-the-superpaintcomponentg-do/): _"You have to overload and call super if you have **"standard" components** (that you don't know how to paint) and other. If your code is 100% your own drawing... you do not need to call super, just do your drawing"_

Comment: -1 for having your paintComponent method dispose of the Graphics object that was passed in to it. This should never be done. To @user3215804: You should not have accepted this dangerous answer but rather MadProgrammer's comprehensive and correct answer. 1+ to it.